# laravel route with parameter not coming from url

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

I have multiple routes that look like this:

```
Route::get('pending-submit', 'CasesController@cases');
Route::get('submited', 'CasesController@cases');
Route::get('closed', 'CasesController@cases');
```

I have been looking around even in the router API documentation and I can't find a solution for my requirement other than creating multiple methods within the controller. The method does the exact same query except for adding a where clause to identify the different status between each case, what I was trying to do is have a method like this

```
public function cases($whereStatus = 0){
    return Cases::where('status', $whereStatus)->get();
}
```

Instead of doing this:

```
public function pendingCases(){
    return Cases::where('status', 0)->get();
}

public function submitedCases(){
    return Cases::where('status', 1)->get();
}

public function closedCases(){
    return Cases::where('status', 2)->get();
}
```

But I can figure a way to pass that parameter to the method from the route so I now have to create a method for each route which does not seem necessary to me. I understand I could just generate urls with the get parameter in it but I wanted to make that cleaner, is there a way for me to add that parameter without having it in the url?

By the way, I also tried something like this which did not wok:

```
Route::get(
    'pending-submit',
    array(
        'uses'   => 'CasesController@cases',
        'params' => array(
            'filter' => 0
        )
    )
);
```

---

EDIT:

I understand I can make URLs like https://someurl.com/cases?status=0 and can also have URLs like https://someurl.com/cases which require a different method per route however what I want is have URLs like https://someurl.com/cases and have a single method where the parameter is passed by the router instead of me getting it from the request so I can do it like this:

```
public function myMethod($param){
    /*
     * Here I access the $param without calling Request::input('someparam');
     * or without Request::path() where then I have to check what path is it
    */
    echo $param; /* this should already have the param from the route */
}
```

---

EDIT:

@AndyNoelker what I have is 3 different values either 0, 1 or 2

I want to have something like this

```
Route::get(
    'cases',
    array(
        'uses'   => 'CasesController@cases',
        'status' => 0 /* this is what I need */
    )
);
```

If not possible from the routes.php it is fine, I just want to know, all other methods you are giving me is not what I want or asking for since I already know how to do those.

Comment: If you do not want to pass in any data through your route and you want to use the exact same route to retrieve different results, where do you want that data (that tells what the status is) passed in? Is it saved to a user that is logged in? Your controller needs to access that from *somewhere*. Where do you want it to be, if not in the route itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are going to have to pass the desired status in through the URL - otherwise the route will have no way of knowing which status you desire. You can either do it through URL query parameters or as a fully-fledged route parameter. I would personally suggest using a query parameter in this case, but I'll show you both.

### Using Query parameters

URL

```
example.com/cases?status=1
```

Routes

```
Route::get('cases', CasesController@cases);
```

CasesController

```
public method cases(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $status = $input['status'];

    return Cases::where('status',$status)->get();
}
```

### Using Route parameters

URL

```
example.com/cases/1
```

Routes

```
Route::get('cases/{id}', CasesController@cases);
```

CasesController

```
public method cases($id)
{
    return Cases::where('status',$id)->get();
}
```

Of course if you'd prefer that they use a slug or something other than a unique id in the route, then you'd have to adjust for that in your query, but this should give you the right idea.

Comment: Sorry @AndyNoelker but this does not answer the question, I know I can use that and is even mentioned in my question and is exactly what I am trying to avoid

Comment: Your question states that you feel like you have to create a new method in your controller for each status. This shows that you do not - it can all be handled in one method. It is your choice how you pass the data through the route. Can you clarify your question then?

Comment: here is the question which is also in the main question: "I understand I could just generate urls with the get parameter in it but I wanted to make that cleaner, is there a way for me to add that parameter without having it in the url?"

Comment: You have to have *some* way of passing the data through the route, which will require something in the URL. Are you wanting to make completely different routes for each case, like you show at the very top of your post? If so, I can edit my answer for that purpose.

Comment: Check it out now. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I want to have a single method since there is only a small variation and the rest of the method is the same for three routes, I am trying to do it so function someFunction($filter){} has the $filter variable passed but not through the url making that blind to the user so they only see https://someurl.com/cases instead of https://someurl.com/cases?status=0 I undertand it is not a problem for me to do https://someurl.com/cases?status=0 or to have different methods for each route but I wanted to know if that was possible and if so how would I pass the parameter to the router

Comment: So you want to use completely different routes to filter between the different statuses then, instead of using query parameters or route parameters? My edited answer does this. You can use that same method on 100 different routes and it will produce a different query for each one based on the name of the route.

Comment: yes it does what you say, however that is still not my question, please read the actual questions before answering them, people may not want what you offer as an alternate solution, my question is very clear, Is this possible from the route (yes(how), no(fine))

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for route parameters:

```
Route::get("/cases/{case}", "CasesController@cases");
```

This will match any of the following:

```
some_url/cases/pending-submit
some_url/cases/submited
some_url/cases/closed
...
```

Then, your function `public function cases` in `CasesController` would look like this:

```
public function cases($case){
    if($case == "pending-submit"){
      // Do Something
    } else if($case == "submited") {
      // Do Something Else
    }

    // OR
    return Cases::where('status', $case)->get();
}
```

Etc etc. Look more into `url` parameters here: [Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, I used it like this: Route::get("{type}", "CasesController@cases")->where('type', 'pending-submit|pending-review|read|stored');

Comment: Hmm. I've never actually seen it done that way, but it's pretty clever. Glad I could help though!

Comment: This is exactly what I showed you in my original answer under the 'Using Route Parameters' section. I guess you didn't read my entire answer. I changed it back for reference.

Comment: @AndyNoelker Hmm. You totally did, now I feel bad for posting this, and since you had edited your question, I didn't see that you had posted the same thing already. I'll upvote your answer. Sorry about that!

Comment: Oh it's definitely not your fault, my comment was aimed at @TlacaelelRamonLuis. I think he didn't read past the part about query parameters, knew he didn't want those, and rejected my answer.

Comment: @AndyNoelker I know, and I assumed it was aimed at him, but I still feel bad :P

Comment: @AndyNoelker yes you are right, I just did not see it that way, as I had not thought on limiting the route via a regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Route::get('pending-submit', array('status' => 0, 'uses' => function(){
   $CasesController = $app->make('CasesController');
   return $CasesController->callAction('cases', $parameters = array());
 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, this should work.

**Web Route**

```
Route::get('pending-submit', [
    'as'        => 'pending',
    'uses'      => 'CasesController@cases',
    'status-id' => '0'
]);
```

And, you can access the parameter passed with the route like below,

**In Controller**

```
$request->route()->getActions('status-id')
```

**In View**

```
{{ request()->route()->getAction('status-id') }}
```

Tested and perfectly works in L5.6