# Laravel - How to pass a variable to controller through resource route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.4, laravel-controller

I've defined this resource in `web.php` of Laravel app,

```
Route::resource('Student', 'StudentCtrl');
```

and I have a variable which contains name of meta file,

```
$metaFile = 'student_meta.json';
```

I want to pass `$metaFile` to `StudentCtrl`, so I can catch the file name there.

I'm using Laravel 5.4.

Thanks.

Comment: your question does not make sense, are you passing a variable from the URL? if so read the resoursfull routing if it is not (which i am suspecting) you can put that variable in the control itself why are you trying to put it in the routes?

Comment: Where is this variable coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the variable to the url, And thats it.

if its a `get` request will be routed to `StudentCtrl@show`

if its a `put` request will be routed to `StudentCtrl@update`

if its a `delete` request will be routed to `StudentCtrl@destroy`

And so on.

All you have to do is to define a method of the form. `GET`,`POST`,`PUT/PATCH`,`DELETE`.

Have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Passing a single variable from Router to Controller is possible only for Single HTTP request method.

**Refer here :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/50405137/9809983

For a complete resource route, its possible to send a fixed value to all views under that resource, if that's what you are trying to do

**In Controller**

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
    {  
        $action_array = $request->route()->getAction();
        $json_file['json_file'] = "student_meta.json";
        $new_action_array = array_merge($action_array, $json_file);
        $request->route()->setAction($new_action_array);

    }
```

Now you can access the value in all the views under the resource controller like,

**In View**

```
{{ request()->route()->getAction('json_file') }}
```

Tested and perfectly works in Laravel 5.6